# java hasNextInt issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I working on a code as follows:

```
public class SampleIntReader{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value = 0;
        while(s.hasNextInt()){
            value = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
 }
```

I would like the code to stop reading like in `BufferedReader`, which terminates with `eof` or `-1` or `null` where we don't have to check explicitly the terminating condition. But with `Scanner` class we have only `hasNextInt` and `nextInt` method. Writing a terminating code looks ugly within the `while` loop.
Is there an elegant way for using `Scanner` class.

Moreover, Scanner class behaves differently in Windows and Linux environments.

Comment: "But with Scanner class we have only hasNextInt and nextInt method." Are you sure about that?

Comment: What is your aversion to checking for `-1`?  And isn't it a good thing to have more control?

Comment: @d.j.brown: With respect to Integer, I found only these two methods.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I don't have aversion for checking for `-1`. But this is done automatically in I/O stream.

Comment: Typically, `System.in` is my keyboard. So how does my keyboard know when it should tell the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` that is reading from it that I'm not going to type in any more integers?

Answer (score 0):

Using a boolean with some sort of exit key:

```
public class SampleIntReader{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = 0;
    boolean done=false;
    while(!done){
        value = s.nextInt();
        if(value==-1){done=true;}//this exits the loop
        System.out.println(value+" Type -1 to stop");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid `if(value==1)` inside the loop. Something like `while ((k = br.read()) != -1)`

Comment: `br.read() != -1` only works to break the loop if `br.read()` actually ever returns -1.  And that can only ever happen if you're reading from a source that can actually reach an end-of-file condition.  Files and network connections, for instance, do have a limited supply of data that can be exhausted after enough reads.  A user's keyboard, however, might _never_ run dry (unless the user is on UNIX and knows about the Control/D convention...)